# How to print the first few records using SeqIO from Biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, enumerate, fasta

I have a fasta file that has several hundred records but I'm trying to return a table with just the first 20 records (record description, AA length, and name).

My code is not working and I would like to know how to return just the first 20 records - preferably in a table format.

This is my python code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import cgi
import re
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
from Bio import SeqIO
for index, record in enumerate(SeqIO.parse("e_coli_k12_dh10b.faa", "fasta")): print(record.description, len(record.seq))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to do this. The most similar to your current structure would be to add a `break` when the index hits 19 (that is the 20th number since counting starts at 0):

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for index, record in enumerate(SeqIO.parse("e_coli_k12_dh10b.faa", "fasta")): 
    print(record.description, len(record.seq))
    if index == 19:
        break
```

However, the way I prefer style-wise is to use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice
from Bio import SeqIO

records = SeqIO.parse("e_coli_k12_dh10b.faa", "fasta")

for record in islice(records, 20):
    print(record.description, len(record.seq))
```

Instead of printing you can insert the descriptions and lengths into a list, array or other data structure of your choosing if you want to store the table.